# Extract code/function by reading php file

Tags: php, regex

i've few PHP files and i want to read but not execute these files to fetch function list from them, i can use `include` and then `get_class_methods` by calling a class but i don't want to do that, i simply just want to read php file and extract function list, i tried some RegEx patterns but it also matches in strings which i dont want.

I used following RegEx pattern but dont want to use it though it dont seems that the solution would be RegEx:

```
preg_match_all("%function ([^(\s]+)%", $source, $func);`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two options:

1. get regex buddy and play around with your regex until it does what it needs to
2. implement the following algorithm:

   1. search for the string "function"
   2. get the characters to the right of function until you encounter " " (whitespace)
   3. when you encounter the "{" after the function name and arguments, declare $c = 1
   4. for each "{" you encounter, increment $c
   5. for each "}" you encounter, decrement $c
   6. when $c == 0, you have reached the end of the function
   7. save the function in a variable
   8. repeat